# Вывод sql из div блока

Tags: php, javascript, html

Здравствуйте, связался с одной проблемой. Из JS у меня выводит в DIV блок число и надо вставить в переменную значение, которое вывело в DIV

```
<div id='iidd'>12</div>
```

PHP:

```
$id = #iidd; //сюда нужно вывести число из div блока
```

Пробовал сделать так:

```
$ids = "<div id='iidd'></div>";
$idssd = htmlspecialchars($ids);
$id = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $idssd);
```

Но проблема возникает при $idssd, он делает в html, но число из JS, которое выводит в div не приносит с собой. Выводил просто $ids отображает число, но и в прибавок с этим , а в переменной $id надо только число

Comment: как div блок с числом попадает из браузера на сервер, где выполняется php?

Comment: JS: `$("#div").text(id);`(id - в переменной), html: `<div id="div"></div>`

Comment: Мне кажется что ты не отправляешь значение в `php`. При вставке значения в `div` с помощью `js` как ты передаешь его в `php`?

Comment: @СашаОсипов - это не ответ на мой вопрос

Comment: Выводил просто $ids отображает число, но и в прибавок с этим div, а в переменной $id надо только число

Comment: `$ids = "<div id='iidd'> **здесь** </div>";` почему у тебя здесь нет числа? Твоя регулярка работает верно.

Comment: @AndrewTymchenko там пусто, потому-что туда из JS вставляется число `$("#iidd").text(id);` таким способом. После выполнения функции открывается модальное окно и в нем эта переменная. Он вставляет число в DIV, но потом делается в HTML, и получается так, как-будто он не успевает вставить число в переменную и поэтому он в HTML перерабатывает без числа.

Comment: Вам нужно понять, что такое http-протокол, и чем клиент отличается от сервера.

Comment: @СашаОсипов а как ты делаешь отправку на сервер своего `div`-блока? Можешь показать код?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не уверен, что понял вопрос правильно, но всё же. Есть вариант отправки переменной на сервер. Т.е. после `$("#div").text(id);` напиши `$.post('script.php',{a:id});`, а в script.php можно записать переменную в файл, а в твоем скрипте считать ее из файла. Либо вместо **script.php** подставь путь до своего скрипта, и там уже обрабатывай

Comment: Сделал. 
JS: `$.post('u/two.php',{"isdsd":id});`
PHP: `$id = $_POST[isdsd];`
Ответ: *пустота*

Comment: Ответ смотришь не там.

Comment: `$.post('u/two.php',{isdsd:id});`  - здесь кавычки убери, а здесь поставь:  `$id = $_POST['isdsd'];`

Comment: @Андрей ни чего не поменялось

Comment: Я понимаю, что скрипт правильный, но серьезно, ответ ни какой не выдает

Comment: Ну тогда я не знаю. Должно работать

Comment: @СашаОсипов добавь себе проверку: `if(isset($_POST['isdsd'])){ echo $_POST['isdsd']; }`

Comment: @AndrewTymchenko пусто

Comment: ты уверен, что передаешь на сервер не пустое значение? Попробуй делать проверку в js перед отправкой

Comment: Делал. `alert(id);` http://prntscr.com/e97aov

Comment: прям мистика какая-то

Comment: Всё, разобрался и решил проблему. Хотел сделать просто одним файлом, потом передумал.

Сделал так

JS:
`$.post('u/mod.php',{id:id},onAjaxSuccess);
function onAjaxSuccess(data){$(".txtmodal").html(data);}`

PHP:
`$id = $_POST['id'];`

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример как ты должен отправлять на сервер значение `div` блока

```js
document.getElementById("some_id").addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  var value = this.innerHTML;
  $.ajax({
   url: './ajax.php',
   type: "GET",
   data: { value_of_div: value },
   success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    console.log('sended!');
   },
   error: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    console.log('error!');
   }
  });
  console.log(value);
  
});

document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("some_id").innerHTML = 13;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some_id">12</div>
```

При нажатии на `div` изменяется значение `div` и происходит отправка на сервер.
Это "тоже самое" что ты изменяешь значение `div` в `js`.

И потом в  файле

**ajax.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['value_of_div'])){
  $value = $_POST['value_of_div']; 
  echo $value;
}
```

Как то так.